# http error 500 en miarroba

Tags: php, mysql, html5, css3

Un blog que me funcionaba bien en localhost con Xampp lo he subido a miarroba, y al intentar verlo en internet me aparece el siguiente error:

> Esta página no funciona La página realzaragoza.webcindario.com no
>   puede procesar esta solicitud ahora. HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Busca los archivos de log de tu aplicación, de apache, nginx o lo que utilices en miarroba. Ahí debes tener más información sobre que está ocurriendo

Comment: ya he mirado pero no aparece ningun error

Comment: Si no es un error del webserver entonces es un error de PHP. Intenta poner `ini_set("display_errors", true")` al principio del primer script que se llama. ¿Es wordpress? Si es así, tendrás que cambiar la URL del blog en la base de datos para que no intente redirigir a Localhost

Comment: por lo que he visto, arroba da servicio de php5, no de php7. Por un casual utilizas la ultima version en tu aplicacion? si es asi puedes tener bastantes problemas con eso... Me extraña que no tengas nada en log. Normalmente en el errors.log o en el access.log (caso de apache) aparecen lineas que te pueden ayudar.